# Unidentified NEC Power IC K828

Tags: power, transistors

I've come across this in a seemingly undated power supply. I know it's bad, but I can't seem to find a replacement, or even a datasheet.

It had a resistor in parallel with it's outer two pins.

Here's a picture, as it should be the most descriptive.

[image: K828]

This is all I know or have available. If there's anything else that would be helpful, just ask. If I could get any help with finding a datasheet, it would be great! Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few references claim that it's similar to the 2SK828, which also gives no info. The 2SK827 is a 450V, 18A switching NMOSFET. The 2SK829 is a 500V, 15A switching NMOSFET. I'd pull up once of those datasheets and look for something comparable.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give a shot at finding something out. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I managed to find a Japanese version here: http://www.datasheetdir.com/2SK828+N-Channel-MOSFETs.

Comment: A fairly good rule for Japanese transistors labeled A123 or K828 is to add 2S in front and search for that...